# key value repeated while iterating over dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

For below code I am observing key value (128) is getting repeated and over-ridden by another (1280) value.

**Code Snippet:**

```
tput = OrderedDict([('1518',0),('1280',0),('1024',0),('512',0),('256',0),('128',0),('64',0)])



with open(freader) as fcsv:
            reader = csv.reader(fcsv)
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    for key, value in tput.iteritems():
                        if re.match(key, str(row[0])) and int(row[1]) == 1:
                            tput[key] = row[7]
                            print " key is ", key, " and value is", tput[key]
```

**Input CSV file contains:**

```
128, 1, 30.0140001774, 177901, 182170952, 100069.492703, 100021.989147, 102422516.887, 1796.00610211, 102423335.704
128, 2, 29.9990000725, 177901, 182170952, 111188.325226, 111576.811204, 114254654.673, 1751.27129964, 113799884.726
128, 3, 29.9839999676, 177901, 182170952, 111188.325226, 111129.135927, 113796235.189, 1737.77562216, 113799885.63
512, 1, 29.9990000725, 75851, 310689185, 71111.1111111, 71085.2360028, 291165126.667, 1757.00878208, 291280637.718
512, 2, 29.9989998341, 75851, 310689185, 71111.1111111, 71111.7041168, 291273540.062, 1842.45717257, 291280640.032
512, 3, 30.013999939, 75851, 310689185, 71111.1111111, 71071.7000179, 291109683.273, 1825.21859093, 291135066.628
1280, 1, 30.013999939, 34441, 352677802, 36593.7661443, 31965.1829796, 327323473.712, 944.594757643, 327323473.712
1280, 2, 30.0140001774, 34441, 352677802, 36593.7661443, 31917.3050689, 326833203.906, 936.91688291, 326833203.906
1280, 3, 29.9979999065, 34441, 352677802, 36593.7661443, 31941.9962326, 327086041.422, 927.958137658, 327086041.422
1518, 1, 30.013999939, 29010, 352303919, 29010.5335866, 26742.8533895, 324765211.562, 770.532335849, 324765211.562
1518, 2, 29.9979999065, 29010, 352303919, 29010.5335866, 26674.55193, 323935758.638, 800.026664257, 323935758.638
1518, 3, 30.013999939, 29010, 352303919, 29010.5335866, 26822.7885119, 325735943.689, 772.290818704, 325735943.689
```

**Output observed:**

```
 key is  128  and value is  102422516.887
 key is  512  and value is  291165126.667
 key is  1280  and value is  327323473.712
 key is  128  and value is  327323473.712    --> key 128 again overrides 1280 value
 key is  1518  and value is  324765211.562
```

I feel I am doing standard iteration- Unable to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match(pattern, string)` matches a pattern at the beginning of the string.
`re.match('128', '1280')` therefore returns a matcher object which is truthy.

Why don't you just compare equality:

```
if key == str(row[0]) and ...
```

or don't loop through the dict at all, but check for the key:

```
 if str(row[0]) in tput:
     tput[key] = row[7]
```

Comment: got it.. Yes now I am asking myself the same question whey did I chose to use re.match :)